Multiple imputation of longitudinal data in SPSS
I'm attempting to analyse a longitudinal, retrospective dataset with measurements at various time-points. The data-set has a significant amount of missing data, up to 30% for the main outcome variable, and as such, I would like to perform multiple imputation to account for this.
The dataset currently is in the long format, and while multiple imputation will run, I highly suspect it to disregard any previous measurements of the subject and treat each time-point as a separate case, which would make any imputed data less acurate.
My questions are as follows:

Is it possible to use multiple imputation on a longitudinal dataset in the long format in SPSS while respecting the longitudinal data?
If not, is it wise to transform the data to a wide format and use that to impute the data, or is it more advisable to attempt to switch to a different analysis program (I also have access to Rstudio and STATA)?

Many thanks in advance!

Welcome to CrossValidated.  I think an SPSS listserv is probably a better place to ask this question, though.  You might see https://spsstools.net/en/resources/notes/how-to-get-help-from-spss-community/where-can-i-find-help-on-my-spss-problem/

Even if you wanted to conduct the imputation in R, chances are it'd make sense to convert to wide format in SPSS first.
